# float left/margin for two static width divs (ie6)

Tags: css, margin, css-float, internet-explorer-6

Ok, I have the following layout/CSS:

```
div#wrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1400px;
}

div#header {
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 15px 0 50px;
    width: 135px;
}


div#blog {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 15px 0 50px;
    width: 1080px;
}

div#site {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

with:

```
<div id="site">
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="blog"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, site covers window, 'wrap' is fixed width and is centered and 'header' and 'blog' are inside 'wrap' with defined width.

The problem is as usual with IE6. 'blog' is shown under the 'header'. So it seems that float and/or margin does not work.

It seems that it's not a double margin float bug, at least in DebugBar I see correct margins, but also there are some offsets (50px for header), which I don't know what it is, actually. Anyway, i tried to add 'display: inline' to both 'header' and 'blog', and it does not help.

I don't have ie7 to see, but it does show correctly in ie8.

I went through several tutorials on floating bugs for ie6, but could not find a solution for my problem (or i might have missed it).

Any ideas how to 'heal' it without adding extra div's (i hope it's possible with css, like with doublemargin bug)

p/s/ total width of divs with margin is 1345 < 1400.

EDIT1: 
the only thing that is strange is 'wrap' has 0 height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT1: the only thing that is strange is 'wrap' has 0 height.

Please read http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html . However, the described issue doesn't appear in IE6 because of another bug; floats are automatically cleared.

Also, to prevent double-margin bug, make sure you define `display:inline` for all floating elements. Avoid adding `display: inline` to `#wrap`, it'll cause the previous issue (`#blog` appearing under `#header`).

edit: I was able to reproduce the issue at reznikdavydov.com. Inside `#header`, there is a `<div class=menu>` which has `width: 300px` set. The [bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html) in IE6 causes that the wrapper (`#header`) is incorrectly expanded so that `div.menu` cannot overflow out of it. This is the reason why `#header` and `#blog` cannot fit side by side: the computed with of `#header` is 135px in modern browser, but 300px in IE6. The solution is to remove the `width:300px` rule from `.menu` selector.

Comment: thank you for a link. That worked (as expected), not height is non-zero.

Comment: but the funny thing is that 'display:inline' for both 'header' and 'blog' does not help

Comment: @Denis Are you *sure*? Please provide a JSFiddle demo or link to a problematic website. I've just copied your code, defined `display:inline` for `#header` and `#blog` and the result is http://i.imgur.com/toPcm.png

Comment: the link to the site is: reznikdavydov.com   I check it under VM in OpenSuse with IE6.0 from someones pack (IE3, IE4, IE5.0, IE5.5, IE6). Please, let me know if it does work under your IE6.

Comment: it might be that IE6 I use is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have unneeded CSS, i would start from here and see if it works

```
div#wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 1400px;
}

div#header {
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 15px 0 50px;
    width: 135px;
}


div#blog {
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 15px 0 50px;
    width: 1080px;
}

div#site {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i wish i could help more but i am on a Mac and cannot reproduce your problem.